# PHP is not sending values to database using a simple form

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Hello I am using PHPStorm and I am trying to send data to my database using php.
When the form is submitted my database creates a new id which is set to auto-increment but the values are empty!

This is my html form in a file called create_account.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NABI| Find the perfect music teach today!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale      =1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="info.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="send">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my info.php file

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $db = "nabi_data";
    $pass = "";
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (name)
    VALUES ('$name')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

This is how my database table looks like

[just_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWvt4.png)

Comment: So what did you try ? Have you tried to echo your sql query to see its content ?

Comment: Try printing `$name` after your filter_input to debug log file to make sure it actually has a value

Comment: Please change the input type text box name and then try once.

Comment: Hi @Loufylouf this is what shows when I echo the $sql query --INSERT INTO just_name (name) VALUES ('')--

Comment: Well then, you have a problem with your `$name` variable. Try a `print_r($_POST)` at the beginning and a `var_dump($name)` after the filtering.

Comment: @Laufylouf I tried the print_r and var_dump this is what I get--Array ( ) INSERT INTO just_name (name) VALUES ('')NULL---

Comment: *"I am using PHPStorm"* - That's an editor and not a browser/webserver. You need to execute your file as `http://localhost/file.php` and not from inside PHPStorm or `file:///file.php` if that's what's you're doing.

Comment: `$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` you're getting undefined index because your entire code is in the same file. You need to use a conditional statement for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have Xampp installed and I am executing my file as http://localhost:63342/nabi/info.php... How do I use a conditional statement here?

Comment: it's in my answer below @VanessaCharles

Comment: @VanessaCharles I see `id="name"` are you using JS/Ajax with this that you haven't included in your question?

Comment: @VanessaCharles are you able to upload `create_account.php` somewhere online so we can view? Might be able to see something via "view source". I think the basic problem here is that $_POST is empty, need to solve that.

Comment: @avip I am trying to figure out how to upload create_account.php

Comment: @VanessaCharles if you have hosting somewhere you can upload there but you can also cut and paste the "view source" text from your browser to pastebin.com and share a link here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do not have any ajax programmed or written yet but I added the ids to it would be ready for ajax/js

Comment: <!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NABI| Find the perfect music teach today!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale =1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="info.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
    <input type="submit" value="send">



</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @avip just selected all copied and pasted all the coding from create_account.php  in the comment not sure if that is easy to see.

Comment: @VanessaCharles a bit hard to read but I can see it's the same as in your original posted question, just making sure there isn't some extra stuff that might be interfering. I think the other question I have is, what version of PHP is this?

Comment: @avip this is what phpAdmin says -- PHP version: 5.6.15

Comment: @VanessaCharles This shouldn't be necessary as it's the default but try: `<form method="post" action="info.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">` and `var_dump($_POST)` as the first line in `info.php`

Comment: @avip Hey I changed the form action and ectype and I var_dump as the first line and it returned an empty array

Comment: @VanessaCharles very strange! Hmm, can you check php.ini on your server and post the line `post_max_size`?

Comment: @avip so you mean open the php.int file and paste "post_max_size"?

Comment: @VanessaCharles yeah

Comment: @avip I just tried that. No luck. Do you thing php.ini has to do with this? Does the debugger have something to do with this to?

Comment: @VanessaCharles you should most definitely have a php.ini file, I just wanted to verify that line didn't have some strange setting or set to 0. The debugger could be interfering in some way, turn it off and see if the code works as is?

Comment: @avip I finally found the file this is what it says 'post_max_size = 8M'

Comment: @VanessaCharles that setting is correct; sometimes people change it manually and use 'MB' which is incorrect and then PHP interprets that as 0. Was just making sure that wasn't the case. But, since you mentioned the debugger I think the issue is actually the IDE, see my answer below and try the solution in there?

Comment: what does `post_max_size = 8M` have anything to do here? That's only good for handling "files" and not "text" input. Your question makes no more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an echo, Does It return the name value?

....

Try to get name field content with $_POST['name'];

Comment: Thank you @Parene but this is what I get when I set $name = $_POST['name']; ---Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Vanessa\PhpstormProjects\nabi\info.php on line 6---

Answer (score 0):

> *"Thank you @Parene but this is what I get when I set $name = $_POST['name']; ---Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Vanessa\PhpstormProjects\nabi\info.php on line 6--- – Vanessa Charles 5 mins ago"*

`$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` you're getting undefined index because you're not checking if it's empty or not.

You need to use a conditional statement for it while checking if it's "empty".

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');

if(!empty($name)){

// do something as in "enter" it in the database

$name = $name;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (name)
VALUES ('$name')";

// ... rest of your query here

}
```

---

**Edit:**

Modify your code to read as this and copy/paste it exactly as show and reload it while clearing your cache.

I also added ticks to the `name` column, sometimes that helps.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $db = "nabi_data";
    $pass = "";

    if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
       $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    else {
       echo "Something went wrong.";
    }

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (`name`) VALUES ('$name')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

A prepared statement should be used for this though.

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

**I.e. as a prepared statement:**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $db = "nabi_data";
    $pass = "";

    if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
       $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    else {
       echo "Something went wrong.";
    }

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO just_name (`name`) VALUES (:name)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: The OP clearly says that there is a `create_account.php` and `info.php` files.

Comment: @Loufylouf *"Here is my info.php file"* - `<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $db = "nabi_data"; ....` and `action="info.php"`

Comment: @Loufylouf either way, they're getting an undefined index notice. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- I just added the conditional statement and I dont get the error anymore but I still have the same problem with the null values in the database. :(

Comment: @VanessaCharles what is the column type and length for `name`? MySQL could be failing silently if it isn't the right type but most importantly it's length.

Comment: @VanessaCharles I also made a slight edit to my answer, adding `$name = $name;` inside the conditional statement.

Comment: In the comments of the question, OP says that a `print_r($_POST)` just returns `Array()` which worries me way more than the column length.

Comment: @Loufylouf *Hmm....* that is strange. I fear that we may not be seeing full code and that doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @VanessaCharles Try changing the `$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` to `$name = $_POST['name'];` if that works, then your filter's failing you for some reason. I also made a mention in comments that you're using PHPStorm with this. You can't use that to execute code. Run it from your web browser. Your mention of PHPStorm is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Fred-ii  I just use the if not empty conditional statement added my code and then added an else statement that echoes "this is empty b" and it did echo that. I guess it is empty. And after the conditional statement nothing is being sent to the database not even empty values.

Comment: @VanessaCharles then try changing `$conn->exec($sql);` to `$conn->query($sql);` I honestly don't know what else to do here. You also need to answer the other questions I asked here, about the column type and length and PHPStorm.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the column type and length is varchar(255)

Comment: @Fred-ii- just changed the exc to query and still it is echoing as empty :(

Comment: @VanessaCharles Change `$sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (name)
VALUES ('$name')";` to `$sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (name)
VALUES ('john')";` if that doesn't work, then something strange is going on.

Comment: Hi Fred-ii- Yes that works! It does insert John to the database!

Comment: @VanessaCharles Reload my answer under **Edit**, if that fails then I am seriously asking myself questions as to why that would fail. There's also a prepared statement example I wrote up. New edit here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just copied and pasted your code to create_account.php and this  is what I got Something went wrong.
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\Users\Vanessa\PhpstormProjects\nabi\info.php on line 23

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Comment: @VanessaCharles Reload my answer under the **Edit** and see the one under **I.e. as a prepared statement:** I forgot to remove the `$sql` variable and simply changed to `echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- I copied and pasted the one with the prepared statement and i get this ---Something went wrong.Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null---- I also used the one without the prepare statement and that one echoes "New record entered successfully" and it enters a new id to the database but again with the missing values in the name colunm

Comment: @VanessaCharles *"New record entered successfully"* I didn't include that in my answer and this tells me you're not using my answer *exactly* as shown. So, I don't know what your code looks like. I've tested this with no problems, so there isn't anything else I can do here, sorry. Try creating a new table or checking if your database is corrupted somehow. That's about all I can do here for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You actually did. You gave two set of codes one with the prepare statement and one without the prepare statement. The one without the prepare statement has that message... But thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: @VanessaCharles You're welcome. Btw, are you even entering anything in that input?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the "undefined index" error, you may want to do something like this:

```
if ($_POST and !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $db = "nabi_data";
    $pass = "";

    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');

    // debugging step to check to see what you're getting back from the filter_input call (or write it to a log)
    var_dump($name); exit;

    if ($name != '') {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO just_name (name) VALUES ('$name')";
            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else {
        // filtered name was blank; raise an error and/or redirect them to create_account.php
    }

    $conn = null;
}
else {
    // handle this case; maybe just redirect back to create_account.php
}
```

The biggest key is to check that "name" exists in the `$_POST` (also accessible through the `$_REQUEST` global variable); you can do that through [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

(And yes, as others have suggested, checking the value you get in `$name` after the `filter_input` call would be a great thing to verify if you haven't already.)

Comment: From the doc on the first argument of `filter_input` : type
One of INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or INPUT_ENV.

Comment: @Loufylouf, huh, very nice, learn something new every day.  :)

Comment: To be fair, I learned the existence of this function thanks to this question :)

Comment: Hi Davis I get this message trying your code --
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in C:\Users\Vanessa\PhpstormProjects\nabi\info.php on line 33---

Comment: @VanessaCharles, there must be something different in your code as I'm able to run that same code without issue. I would suggest editing your answer with exactly your code, but it looks like you're making it further with Fred. You would of course need `<?php` tags, which weren't in the snippet I provided. Other than that, the code, as it sits, parses without an issue (PHP 5.6.17) for me.

Comment: @Davis thank you so much! Will keep trying to get thins going :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using PhpStorm built-in web server which has issues with POST.
 As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server, try using that by selecting "PHP Built-in Web Server" type of Run/Debug Configuration.

Or try this manually:

```
cd ~/www/your_project
php -S localhost:8000
```

Here's the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Hi Avip I think you are definitely up to something here. I you are right. But how to I do select the PHp Builtin Web server. Can you walk me through it pls? Sorry Im really new to all of this

Comment: No worries, just not sure I've the same version of the IDE as you. Can you try [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/php-built-in-web-server.html?origin=old_help)

Comment: You can test out the idea though by trying the commands above btw: just change directory to where your php files are, then do `php -S localhost:8000` and then navigate to `http://localhost:8000/path/here/create_account.php`

Comment: which is something I told the OP countless times already but she never gave me any response in regards to running this under PHPStorm. She needs to run this under a webserver with PHP/MySQL installed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you mentioned `file://` vs properly running it on a webserver. But I think OP's issue is worse, the server is running but it's buggy :( either way, we'll find out if that's the issue soon when OP updates...

Comment: @Avip Hi Avip I have no idea how to set "PHP Built-in Web Server"

Comment: @avip I left her [*this comment...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226518/php-is-not-sending-values-to-database-using-a-simple-form/36227911?noredirect=1#comment60084753_36226518) ok (lol) not countless times but what I did say was *"That's an editor and not a browser/webserver."* being the keyphrase here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- fair enough :) I think a certain level of "wtf is going on"/desperation has to be reached before those answers are considered lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I should take the project folder which in this case in Nabi from PHPStorm prijects folder and move it to the xampp folder???

Comment: @Avip ok I will look into the manual sorry im super new to all of these!

Comment: @avip No idea. I answered a similar question not so long ago, where the OP was using PHPStorm the same way. They executed the "normal" way via a web browser using the localhost syntax and *BAM!*... success ;)